# why does not address of non-exist extern variable equal to null

Tags: objective-c

I found something very confusing about non-exists extern variable.
As the code below, obviously, compiler will generate an error cause there is not a int variable named iiii.

But, if the line code of "NSLog(@"%p", &iiii);" is deleted, no error will be generated. And the "not null" will be printed if I execute the output binary.

Why is this happen? I am hoping to get an error, no matter how I manipulate iiii.

Thanks for your help

IDE: Xcode 10.3 with clang
Target platform: iOS simulator 12.4

```
extern int iiii;
if(NULL != (&iiii)) {
    NSLog(@"not null");
}
NSLog(@"%p", &iiii);
```

Comment: In C, the code wouldn't link (assuming it compiled — it won't because it is Objective-C and not C, but it could fairly easily be modified to compile as C) unless there was a definition of `iiii` somewhere — so the address would not be null because no actual object has a null address.  When you remove the second `NSLog()`, the optimizer knows that the condition is always true, so it doesn't need to actually test the variable's address; it cannot be null so `not null` is printed without any test, or need for the variable to be defined.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  This is a C question. `int iiii` isn't an object. If the Objective-C part `NSLog(@"not null");` is replaced by `printf("not null\n");`, no error will be generated. The compiler knows that the condition is always true with and without the second `NSLog()`.

Comment: @Willeke — The use of @ in front of the strings means that the code is not C.  If the OP wanted it to be a C question, there would be no Code that is intrinsically Objective-C, and no tag for Objective-C.

Comment: @Willeke — with the second call to `NSLog()`, there must be an actual variable `iiii` so its address can be determined and printed.  The test can still be optimized away; regardless of where it is stored, it’s address will not be null

Comment: @JonathanLeffler -- code of objc is not important, I have tried to replace objc code with pure C code(https://repl.it/languages/c), I got same result.

Comment: @Willeke -- I am agree with you, I tried to replace objc code with pure C code, and test it on https://repl.it/languages/c, compiler generated a warning said that the bool test is always true. So, I think compiler just optimized bool test if the last line of code was deleted. I still has a question, this behaviou seems odd to me, is this expected or just something undefined? Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building an application includes the distinct stages of *compilation* and *linking*.

It is the linking stage, which occurs after compilation, that global declarations and "`extern`" references to such declarations and linked together. If you look at the error you get when the `NSLog()` is in your code you will see it is a linker (coming from `ld`, the linker/loader) error.

During compilation the compiler assumes that any `extern` references will be resolved by the linker. So it assumes the `iiii` variable will exist, and as such it will have an address so it can optimise away the test.

The above assumes strong linking, when a compiler is informed that *weak linking* will be used then it cannot make the assumption that an external reference will be non-null. E.g. if the variable `iiii` was declared in a library/framework which was weakly dynamically linked to your application then the compiler could not assume the variable existed and the application would need to test somewhere that the weakly-linked dynamic library was present. However we're getting into another topic entirely... (ask a new question if you have a dynamic linking issue).

HTH